# Text view with background of a chat bubble

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have made a text view , and i have set his background to be 
a chat bubble image , i try to add text to this text view, the problem is the text is going out of the bubble image bounds , I perfectly understand why.

My question is , is there a way to force the text to be inside it?

Comment: use a nine patch png image

Comment: google for `nine patch png image`

Comment: It's a kind of format of image which contains borders.

Comment: first non "google" URL: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: Could you post the code and css you use to set the background?

Comment: @pskink  i used your suggestion yet for some unknown reason when i try to draw the borders it doesnt draw anything any ideas?

Comment: no your code, no my ideas

Answer (score 1):

The nine patch is an option, but if you want a quick solution maybe you can play with the paddings to set the text inside it, and set the gravity to center. Example:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextviewwithbacground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/a_intro_tv_start_bordered"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of a 9patch is a good solution.

You can use the 9patch tools from the sdk, yet i found a website which makes it a lot more comfortable.

A great site:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Hope it helps someone.